# Compare date field columns to restrict difference in days between the two

Tags: datetime, forms

I have an ad space website, where a person can place an advert, but for a maximum of 30 days.

To do this, I have a [date field](https://www.drupal.org/project/date) with a calendar popup and collect an end date on field. So it's one field collecting both dates. I need to validate the input of the end date by comparing it to the first field (start date).
I have the [field validation module](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_validation) installed, but I'm not sure how to configure it.

How do I configure it? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field validation module does what you want, the interface description can be confusing.

1. On your **Manage fields** screen click the **validate** action link for your relevant date field.
2. For your field you want to add a **Date range2** validation rule.
3. Name your rule in **Rule name** to a memorable description.
4. For **column** select *value2* to validate your end date.
5. For **Cycle of date** select *global* so you can validate against time relative to the start date.
6. For **Maximum date** set it to "+30 day" (or any [`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) compatible relative string) so that the end date is, ***at most***, 30 days from the start date.
7. Set your your **Custom error message**.
8. Click **Save rule**.

Comment: Thank you very much, that did the trick! Yeah, interface is a bit confusing. Thanks for your help.